# Dynamics CRM 2015: Set default value in JScript without making form dirty

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I want to set default values on account form by JavaScript. I use OData to read these defaults and there is some logic.

I use standard way to set these values:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("myField").setValue(defaultValue);
```

Now this field is **marked dirty** and auto save will save it after 30 seconds. Can I prevent this? I tried to work with setSubmitMode function, didn't work out.

Is there another way to set values in JScript without making it dirty?

Comment: Tagging along, I need the same in 2016 v8.1

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set `setSubmitMode('never')` for this `field` on the form's onLoad() event, also then add a function for this fields' `onChange()` that then changes the `setSubmitMode('always')` again.

Theoretically this field wont then get submitted by MSCRM after doing the setValue(), but a new event triggering the onChange() event like the user manually changing it, will instruct MSCRM to change this and submit the field.